# Can you combine methods and capture the output?

Tags: methods, tcl

I have a method that looks like this:

```
proc getJobinfo {question} {
    puts -nonewline "$question: "
    flush stdout
    gets stdin answer
    # Can you combine totitle and trim into one line?
    set titledanswer [string totitle $answer]
    return $titledanswer
}
```

I would like to call `trim` and `totitle` in one line, is that possible?

For example, in `Python`:

```
company_name : str = userInput.trim().title()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes , you can :
`set titledanswer [string trim [string totitle $answer]]`